# Validating iphone receipt from c++

Tags: iphone, c++, post, validation, receipt

I'm trying to validate an iphone receipt from a c++ server (I have the receipt encrypted with base64, I'm composing a json object according to apple docs, and then I open a socket to the sandbox and send a POST request).

The server responds with error 503 Service Unavailable.

I suspect that I don't compose the POST request correctly.Does anyone know how should look the POST request for the apple store ?

Thanks

Comment: This may be related [In-app purchasing fail on iTunes is starting to bug developers](http://www.engadget.com/2011/09/23/in-app-purchasing-fail-on-itunes-is-starting-to-bug-developers/)

Comment: Interesting, ... I'll check again in a couple of hours

Comment: The [sandbox](https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) should be working fine, the service appears to be up and responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, in this case the problem was that I was using the http instead of https.